# Edits to Express routes are being ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I recently moved a web app I was working on locally to a server. When working locally, any changes I would make to my express routes would be reflected. As soon as I moved the app to the server, I noticed that I could comment out every line of code pertaining to my routes, e.g. `app.get('/')` etc.
but those changes would never be reflected, i.e. I would still be served files as if the first version of the website I transferred was still in effect.

Something that is weird, is that any changes not pertaining to routes is taken into consideration, so if I console.log outside of a middleware it will print.

Any idea on how to make sure that express takes into consideration my changes to its routes?

EDIT:

I figured out the issue: somehow, the browser was fetching from localhost even when I was using the remote server's domain (really weird).
As soon as I stopped listening on my local machine, the browser started to make requests to the server.

Comment: Where are you hosting the app ?

Answer (score 0):

Guess your host isn't doing any new **BUILDS**. Check is there's any way to stop process and run the build again.

If you're hosting it on VPS then you can stop all process with SIGTERM or something alike

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I figured out the issue: somehow, the browser was fetching from localhost even when I was using remote's domain (really weird).
As soon as I stopped listening on my local machine, the browser started to make requests to the server.